# Select count(*) from many tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Dear friends I have a requirement to get the count(*) from one table with different criteria. I am using hibernate with spring.I am using below query for that.

```
"select  " +
            "(select count(*)  from enquiry  where business_id="+busid+")  AS allEnqCount,"+
    "(select count(*)  from enquiry where status='"+Constants.ENQ_FALLOWUP+"' and us.business_id="+busid+")  AS followupCount," +
    "(select count(*)  from enquiry where status='"+Constants.ENQ_SITE_VISIT+"'and us.business_id="+busid+")  AS siteVisitCount ," +
    "(select count(*)  from enquiry where status='"+Constants.ENQ_CUST_VISIT+"'and us.business_id="+busid+")  AS customerVisitCount," +
    "(select count(*)  from enquiry where status='"+Constants.ENQ_OFFICE_VISIT+"'and us.business_id="+busid+")  AS officevisitCount,"+
    "(select count(*)  from enquiry where status='"+Constants.ENQ_PENDING+"'and us.business_id="+busid+")  AS pending";
```

But its taking some considerable amount of time . Can you please tell me is there any way that I can do it with minimum time and in a single select clause.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many rows do you have in that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by`:

Something like:

```
select 
      status,
      count(*) 
from enquiry 
where business_id = @busid 
group by status
```

Answer (score 2):

use `CASE`

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN business_id = 'busid' THEN 1 END) allEnqCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ENQ_FALLOWUP' AND us.business_id = 'busid' THEN 1 END) followupCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ENQ_SITE_VISIT' AND us.business_id = 'busid' THEN 1 END) siteVisitCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ENQ_CUST_VISIT' AND us.business_id = 'busid' THEN 1 END) customerVisitCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ENQ_OFFICE_VISIT' AND us.business_id = 'busid' THEN 1 END) officevisitCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ENQ_PENDING' AND us.business_id = 'busid' THEN 1 END) pending
FROM    enquiry
```

just change the values that satisfies your needs.

Comment: Thanks JW. But it is taking the same amount of time as before.

Comment: try adding `INDEX` on *status* and *business_id* eg, `ALTER TABLE enquiry ADD INDEX (business_id, status)` and execute the query again.

Comment: other than adding index , you should also write count(1) in place of count(*) . here 1 is the index of column for primary key .

Comment: @Andreas : thanks man , i definitely would try do clarify this issue as much as i can , but till then i am gonna go with your concept